# split the column in mysql according to another column in the same table

Tags: mysql, format, mysql-workbench, strip

I have the following table format .

```
Name_of_Car                   ||     model            ||   engine_type
VW petrol engine PassatSE     ||     passat           ||   petrol engine
```

I need to Select the value from the above columns as follows .

```
VW passatSE petrol engine .
```

I need to check if the `engine_type` exists in the `name_of_car` field. And if it does exists then strip it select in the format of `brand name`, `model` , `engine_type`.  I need to strip and select from `Name_of_car` column.

Comment: What does "Strip it" mean, and what does "Strip it and Select From" mean. If the `engine_type` exists in the `name_of_car`, like it does in this example, then what do you want returned in your result set.

Comment: Yes . If engine_type column is not null then engine_type value will exists in name_of_car column. then i need to display :
"VW PassatSE petrol engine" in this format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not 100% sure on the output format you want, but you can clean up the `Name_of_Car` field using the MySQL `[REPLACE][1]` function, such as:

```
SELECT REPLACE (Name_of_Car, engine_type, ': '), model, engine_type
from   testcar
```

To get it all as a single string:

```
SELECT CONCAT_WS(' ', REPLACE (Name_of_Car, engine_type, ': '), model, engine_type)
FROM   testcar
```

Assuming your table name is `testcar`.

Comment: This way seems to bring me closer to the format I want. I am just curious why did u use the ** CONCAT_WS(' ', **  first blank space

Comment: The `CONCAT_WS()` function's first parameter is a separator string - see https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat-ws